# Which encryption model (single-key, per-file-key) does APFS use after 10.13 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, encryption, filevault, high-sierra, apfs

Based on Apple's developer [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/Features/Features.html), APFS appears to support three models of disk encryption:

- No encryption
- Single-key encryption
- Multi-key encryption with per-file keys for file data and a separate key for sensitive metadata

Following the upgrade to 10.13 and the in-place filesystem migration from CoreStorage/FileVault/HFS+ to Encrypted APFS, which of these models is in use?

`diskutil` and related tools do not appear to provide any indication of which model is in use, and I would like to know, for the purpose of data recoverability and O(1) secure file erasure capabilities, whether multi-key is in use on my machine and disks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey you asked this a while ago but I asked the same question on the Apple community discussion board recently and apparently we were just misreading that documentation.

APFS uses **both** single-key and multi-key encryption models simultaneously. The single-key system encrypts the container, and each file within it is encrypted with its own key pair.

Comment: Ok but you should provide a link to that discussion